# Design suggestion for decision tree like business logic

Tags: java, data-structures

I am trying to design the data structure to support data that looks like the following
for example, according to the first line if X<=15 and Y<=78.00 and X>625500 i need to populate Z as some value.

Whats the best way to design this so that the data storage and retrieval is efficient and elegant? Will tree work?

P.S. I dont want to store this data set in the database but prefer to store it in java data structures

Thanks a bunch

X                Y                 Z 
<= 15    <= 78.00          > 625,500 
<= 15     <= 78.00            <= 625,500
<= 15   78.01 - 90.00     > 625,500
<= 15   78.01 - 90.00    <= 625,500
<= 15  > 90.00                > 625,500
<= 15  > 90.00            <= 625,500

Answer (score 0):

Since your data is not a custom structure, I think its better if you treat one row as one object & then create it's collection.

For ex:

```
Class Row{
<variables for X, Y, Z>
<getter setter for X, Y, Z>
}

List<Row> myTable .....

myTable.add(row1);
myTable.add(row2);
```

Now with this, you an directly access any row that you want, just do myTable.get(3) to get 3rd row. Now in that object access X Y to calculate Z & set in that object. You can create RowUtil.java to put methods for Z calculations.